# onClick method doesnt work

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
    gl = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    array = new Button[7][6];
    Button btn;
    for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<6; j++)
        {
            btn = new Button(this);
            btn.setId(7*i + j + 1);
            array[i][j] = btn;
            gl.addView(btn);
        }
    }
    turn = 0;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Test1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();               
    if(v instanceof Button)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Test2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        int[] d = GetCellByID(v.getId());
        Button b = (Button)v;
        b.setEnabled(false);
        if(turn == 0)
        {
            b.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            turn = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            b.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            turn = 0;
        }
        array[d[0]][d[1]] = b;
    }
}
```

This is the code, the Toasts are for testing if what the code is running.
The activity implements `OnClickListener`

The `onClick` method does not work, I used it because I have 42 buttons and I can't write 42 `setOnClickListener()` methods for each button.

In the code I create, in two loop, 42 buttons (7*6) and every time each button is pressed it would be disabled and change the background color of the button one time yellow next time red and again.

Answer (score 6):

You are missing to call the following inside the nested `for` loop:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Here, `this` refers to `Activity` which implements `OnClickListener`

Answer (score 6):

set the onClickListner for your button you have missed that.

```
for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<6; j++)
    {
        btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setId(7*i + j + 1);
        array[i][j] = btn;
        gl.addView(btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From the code snipper you've posted, I don't see anything linking the onClick method to your button(s).

Try adding

```
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

into the for-loop

Answer (score 4):

Call method in your onCreate()

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call method in your onCreate()

Try this :

```
yourbuttonname.setOnClickListener(this);
```

or

```
yourbuttonname.setOnClickListener(yourActivity.this);
```